# Max size of URL parameters in _GET

Tags: php

I am accessing a PHP server using REST: all data is passed in a GET request as URL parameters. One of the parameters arrives at the server in the query_string, but it is not in the _GET global. But shortening the parameter (the cutoff seems to be around 512 characters) lets it through.

Assuming I have diagnosed the problem correctly, is there a way to change this maximum size? I have not found any explanation in the documentation, not even a mention of this limit. This is on Debian squeeze / Apache 2.2.16 / PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Maximum length for a GET request is usually around 2k.

Comment: Thanks, but what I need to know is the max length of an individual GET parameter in PHP.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Ok, it seems that some versions of PHP have a limitation of length of GET params:

> Please note that PHP setups with the suhosin patch installed will have
>   a default limit of 512 characters for get parameters. Although bad
>   practice, most browsers (including IE) supports URLs up to around 2000
>   characters, while Apache has a default of 8000.
>
> To add support for long parameters with suhosin, add
>   `suhosin.get.max_value_length = <limit>` in `php.ini`

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#101469

Comment: I could hug you.  The 800+ char ``crypt`` query param being returned from Sage Pay using Form integration simply wan't received by our checkout_process handler, leading it to present the rather unhelpful message "The card could not be authorised!".  FYI I found adding ``php_value suhosin.get.max_value_length 2000`` to .htaccess did not work, I had to add ``suhosin.get.max_value_length=2000`` to the ``[suhosin]`` section of php.ini (and restart httpd) to make the change take effect.  Suddenly my long crypt query param is received, processed, and card payments work again.

Answer (score 0):

See [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)

The length of the url can't be changed in PHP.
The linked question is about the URL size limit, you will find what you want.

Comment: The URL is fine, and the query string has everything. It is just this one parameter (longer than 512 characters) which doesn't show up in _GET.

Comment: @alexinblue Perhaps the value of this variable has some special symbols. Do you use `urlencode()` for the value?

Comment: @Geoffroy as stated, I am using REST: a GET request is quite convenient and I am not willing to change it. The linked article speaks about a practical limit of about 2000 - 4000 characters in IE8; older browsers are not a problem.

Comment: @alexinblue Perhaps you are right. I did my own test, and I got that the max length of one GET param value is 512 bytes.

Comment: @alexinblue By the way, it clearly will not solve this particular problem, but I just wanted to say that you are wrong saying that _PHP is converting everything behind the scenes_. You should always use `urlencode` for GET param values.

Comment: @Karolis the client is sending everything urlencode()d. PHP is getting the correct value in $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] but not in $_GET.

Comment: @alexinblue Rest don't impose to use GET for everything. Use GET to GET a page. To send data, POST it.