# Server is not allowing long GETs parameters

Tags: php, get, tinymce

I'm having a problem with a TinyMCE plugin using long GET parameters. On my development server, the plugin works just fine. However, on the production server, the parameter is ignored.

The plugin is SMImage, it uses parameters like this one:

```
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
```

Which is kinda long, but shouldn't be much of a problem (except on IE of course).

Under the production server, $_GET['get'] is not even defined, since it's ignored by PHP.

Is there a server setting that can be changed perhaps? Under PHP, what defines the maximum length?

I could use POST instead, but I'm not too sure how I could change this part of the plugin:

```
    var get = 'id=1' + '&dir_root=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_directory', '') + '&server=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_server', '') + '&thumbnail_size=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_thumbnail_size', '') + '&show_thumbnail=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_show_thumbnail', '') + '&jpg_quality=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_jpg_quality', '') + '&orderby=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_orderby', '') + '&show_upload=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_show_upload', '') + '&show_image_menu=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_show_image_menu', '') + '&show_folder_menu=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_show_folder_menu', '') + '&show_newfolder=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_show_newfolder', '') + '&thumbnails_perpage=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_thumbnails_perpage', '') + '&upload_filesize=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_upload_filesize', '') + '&check_session_variable=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_check_session_variable', '') + '&document_root=' + ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_document_root', '');
    ed.windowManager.open({
      file: url + '/index.php?get=' + SMImage_BinToHex(SMImage_RC4(get)),
      width: ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_width', '800'),
      height: ed.getParam('plugin_smimage_height', '500'),
      inline: 1
    },
    {
      plugin_url: url
    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get

Comment: Suhosin was indeed installed, just did a custom php.ini with a small modification, and worked great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is good idea, but you could try using cookie as workaround for passing that kind of parameters. In JS, before calling this window open, do smth like

```
document.cookie = 'SMImage_param=' + SMImage_BinToHex(SMImage_RC4(get))
```

and then call `index.php` without parameters. On server-side use

```
$_COOKIE['SMImage_param']
```

for getting this parameter value.

Of course, it will work only if PHP you are calling is on the same domain (but I'm almost sure that for your TinyMCE plugin it's there).

Comment: And, of course, if you have access to server configuration - you should configure it as is mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get instead.

Comment: Yeah Suhosin was installed, just did a php.ini ;) Thanks for taking the time to answer! :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Agree)) I just thought that author has no access to server configuration, so wrote the only hack that came up into mind :)