# jQuery $.get data doesn't appear in PHP $_GET

Tags: php, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using jQuery `$.get` to send some data to my PHP server as the example below:

**Javascript:**

```
var usr_data = JSON.stringify(window.fb_user);
var save_data = {
    cmd         : 'new_suggestion',
    suggestion  : $('#suggestion').val(),
    sender      : usr_data
};

$.get('/class/suggestion.php',
save_data,
function( data ) {
    if (data.result){
        alert('Thanks for your suggestion.');
    } else {
        alert('Error');
    }           
});
```

**PHP:**

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

The usr_data variable is an object containing the Facebook user data that I get when user logs in with his Facebook account.

The problem is that sometimes, depending on available user data, the `sender` variable disappear as below:

```
array(2) {
  ["cmd"]=>
  string(14) "new_suggestion"
  ["suggestion"]=>
  string(15) "Some suggestion"
}
```

I can't post real sender data here, because it's Facebook user data and I couldn't find a way to reproduce the error with fake data or with my facebook data.

**EDIT**

Does anybody know why `sender` isn't appearing on $_GET array?

**EDIT II**

I just found an URL with fake data that reproduce the error.

I created a PHP file called test_get.php with just the line below.

```
<?php var_dump($_GET); ?>
```

And used the URL below:

`http://mysite/test_get.php?cmd=new_suggestion&suggestion=some%20suggestion&sender=%7B%22id%22%3A%221234567890123%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Foo%20Bar%20Baz%22%2C%22first_name%22%3A%22Foo%22%2C%22middle_name%22%3A%22Bar%22%2C%22last_name%22%3A%22Baz%22%2C%22link%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffoobarbaztest%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22foobarbaz%22%2C%22birthday%22%3A%2201%2F01%2F1900%22%2C%22hometown%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%221234567890%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Test%20City%22%7D%2C%22inspirational_people%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22111713915507379%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Pope%20Benedict%20XVI%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22106184866078691%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Romário%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22109601749058079%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Pope%20Benedict%20XVI%22%7D%5D%2C%22gender%22%3A%22male%22%2C%22religion%22%3A%22Cristão%20-%20Católico%22%2C%22political%22%3A%22Foo%20Party%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22foobarbaz%40foobar.foo%22%2C%22timezone%22%3A-5%2C%22locale%22%3A%22pt_BR%22%2C%22languages%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22108083115891989%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Português%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22108177092548456%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Español%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22106059522759137%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22English%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22108224912538348%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22French%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22108106272550772%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22French%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22450169151702580%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Portuguese%22%7D%5D%2C%22verified%22%3Atrue%2C%22updated_time%22%3A%222011-11-02T18%3A43%3A36%2B0000%22%7D`

The result is the same:

```
array(2) {
  ["cmd"]=>
  string(14) "new_suggestion"
  ["suggestion"]=>
  string(15) "some suggestion"
}
```

**EDIT III**

As suggested on comments, there were accented characters on URL. I encoded these characters and tried again with no luck. Here's the correctly encoded URL:

`http://mysite/test_get.php?cmd=new_suggestion&suggestion=some%20suggestion&sender=%7B%22id%22%3A%221234567890123%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Foo%20Bar%20Baz%22%2C%22first_name%22%3A%22Foo%22%2C%22middle_name%22%3A%22Bar%22%2C%22last_name%22%3A%22Baz%22%2C%22link%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffoobarbaztest%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22foobarbaz%22%2C%22birthday%22%3A%2201%2F01%2F1900%22%2C%22hometown%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%221234567890%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Test%20City%22%7D%2C%22inspirational_people%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22111713915507379%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Pope%20Benedict%20XVI%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22106184866078691%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Rom%C3%A1rio%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22109601749058079%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Pope%20Benedict%20XVI%22%7D%5D%2C%22gender%22%3A%22male%22%2C%22religion%22%3A%22Crist%C3%A3o%20-%20Cat%C3%B3lico%22%2C%22political%22%3A%22Foo%20Party%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22foobarbaz%40foobar.foo%22%2C%22timezone%22%3A-5%2C%22locale%22%3A%22pt_BR%22%2C%22languages%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22108083115891989%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Portugu%C3%AAs%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22108177092548456%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Espa%C3%B1ol%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22106059522759137%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22English%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22108224912538348%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22French%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22108106272550772%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22French%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22450169151702580%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Portuguese%22%7D%5D%2C%22verified%22%3Atrue%2C%22updated_time%22%3A%222011-11-02T18%3A43%3A36%2B0000%22%7D`

With this comment, I noticed that jQuery (or my Browser) isn't encoding the accented chars returned by `JSON.stringify(window.fb_user);`

**EDIT IV**

The following URL works, but if I add the final part of the e-mail "@foobar.foo" it fails. Also tried without the e-mail, but with other data, but it also fail.

`cmd=new_suggestion&suggestion=some%20suggestion&sender=%7B%22id%22%3A%221234567890123%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Foo%20Bar%20Baz%22%2C%22first_name%22%3A%22Foo%22%2C%22middle_name%22%3A%22Bar%22%2C%22last_name%22%3A%22Baz%22%2C%22link%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffoobarbaztest%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22foobarbaz%22%2C%22birthday%22%3A%2201%2F01%2F1900%22%2C%22hometown%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%221234567890%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Test%20City%22%7D%2C%22inspirational_people%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22111713915507379%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Pope%20Benedict%20XVI%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22106184866078691%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Romário%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22109601749058079%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Pope%20Benedict%20XVI%22%7D%5D%2C%22gender%22%3A%22male%22%2C%22religion%22%3A%22Cristão%20-%20Católico%22%2C%22political%22%3A%22Foo%20Party%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22foobarbaz`

```
array(3) {
  ["cmd"]=>
  string(14) "new_suggestion"
  ["suggestion"]=>
  string(15) "some suggestion"
  ["sender"]=>
  string(509) "{"id":"1234567890123","name":"Foo Bar Baz","first_name":"Foo","middle_name":"Bar","last_name":"Baz","link":"https://www.facebook.com/foobarbaztest","username":"foobarbaz","birthday":"01/01/1900","hometown":{"id":"1234567890","name":"Test City"},"inspirational_people":[{"id":"111713915507379","name":"Pope Benedict XVI"},{"id":"106184866078691","name":"RomÃ¡rio"},{"id":"109601749058079","name":"Pope Benedict XVI"}],"gender":"male","religion":"CristÃ£o - CatÃ³lico","political":"Foo Party","email":"foobarbaz"
}
```

Comment: Why is `sender` not appearing on `$_GET` array?

Comment: What do you mean by "depending on available user data" and the `sender` variable disappearing? Does it work sometimes?

Comment: Yes, it works sometimes.

Comment: For example, if user doesn't inform Facebook his languages, it doesn't appears on usr_data.

Comment: Try debugging your js code, 'sender' is probably undefined.

Comment: I saw the encoded URL on javascript console and there were a &sender=foobar there.

Comment: Change [sender: usr_data] to [sender: '-'.usr_data.'-'];

It won't solve your problem but it should at least ensure that sender returns something. Once you have done that, see what sender is actually returning and tell us here.

To be honest it sounds like an authentication issue to me, but I don't see why that would make the sender parameter vanish.

Comment: @FacebookAnswers the URL passed to PHP is something like `cmd=new_suggestion&suggestion=some+suggestion&usr_data=huge+json+object+urlencoded` The Facebook data was sent correctly. Some part of it is causing the PHP to ignore that GET variable... I'll try to change some part of it and update the question.

Comment: Well according to your URL, "usr_data" is being passed as a parameter instead of "sender".

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the url instead of copy it from the real URL and made a mistake. I just succeded to reproduce the error with fake data. I'll update the question with this data.

Comment: @FacebookAnswers I updated the question with an example that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your url on my server and it worked fine:

```
array
  'cmd' => string 'new_suggestion' (length=14)
  'suggestion' => string 'some suggestion' (length=15)
  'sender' => string '{"id":"1234567890123","name":"Foo Bar Baz","first_name":"Foo","middle_name":"Bar","last_name":"Baz","link":"https://www.facebook.com/foobarbaztest","username":"foobarbaz","birthday":"01/01/1900","hometown":{"id":"1234567890","name":"Test City"},"inspirational_people":[{"id":"111713915507379","name":"Pope Benedict XVI"},{"id":"106184866078691","name":"RomÃ¡rio"},{"id":"109601749058079","name":"Pope Benedict XVI"}],"gender":"male","religion":"CristÃ£o - CatÃ³lico","political":"Foo Party","email":"foobarbaz@fo'... (length=882)
```

Is your server configured to support utf-8? Do a phpinfo() and see what you get. I get the following:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET     ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

I noticed that the URL contained some odd characters, (Romario, Christaeo etc), perhaps thats an issue without utf-8?

If you need to change http_accept_charset, this may help: http://rackerhacker.com/2007/11/15/change-the-default-apache-character-set/

=== EDIT ===

It turns out, the server was hitting a 512 byte limit for $_GET. Now this varies from web server to web server, which was why it worked fine when we tried it on my server.

Short of upgrading the server the only way around it was to use the jquery .post() instead of .get()

Comment: Are you using MAMP as server? I tried on MAMP and worked also. On my phpinfo there's no HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET. I'll set it and try again.

Comment: I was using Wampserver. It was running PHP 5.3 if that helps. I can try on a couple of production servers too, if you can't yet isolate the issue.

Comment: I edited the question. I encoded the accented chars and tried again with same result. I'm using PHP 5.3.3 at this server and 5.3.6 with MAMP.

Comment: What I would do now is to play around with your test url. The only bit you need modify is after the &sender=

First, for a control, change it to $sender=test

Then check that you can at least see that in the $_GET.

Assuming that works, resubmit the full url, but remove half the text after the sender, and see if you get anything in the $_GET for sender. It may be garbled, depending on how you split the url, but if you get anything you know what half the problem is in. If you don't get anything, split it again, and keep splitting until you do get something. Then work backwards to find error.

Comment: Just added a working subset, but couldn't find another pattern that work.

Comment: Ok, try extending the one that works by adding "&testrecord=justafewcharacters"

So we are adding a new get variable. If that works then the problem isn't the size of the $_GET array, which can be issue on earlier servers.

Also, try using Jquery $.post, and see if you have any luck that way.

Comment: I found the problem. Each GET record can have only 512 bytes. I added a `&testrecord=fewcharacters` and it worked I added a lot of `fewcharactersfewcharactersfewcharacters` until it stop working again and removed some chars until got 512 chars and it worked again.

Comment: This question confirms this problem. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get)

Comment: That link is broken.

But anyway, try using .post() instead then.

Comment: Could you edit your answer with this suggestion on using $.post instead of $.get? This way it'll be easier to other people to know the solution before read all test we did to get this conclusion. The correct URL is the following:  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get)

Comment: Yes! Perfectly! I tried with curl both GET and POST, and just post worked. Thanks!