# How do you generate web pages based on a form?

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

For example, the website https://talky.io/ has a form on its homepage.  When you enter text into the form and hit the button, you're taken to a page that's https://talky.io/[your text].  How do you do this?  What's the best way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onSubmit` and change the `action` attribute of the form via javascript, then return true. The code could look like this:

HTML from linked page:

```
<form id="createRoom">
   <input id="sessionInput" placeholder="Name the conversation" autofocus="autofocus">
   <button type="submit">Let’s go!</button>
</form>
```

Js code:

```
document.getElementById("crateRoom").onsubmit = function(){
   var url = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("sessionInput").value);
   document.getElementById("crateRoom").action = "/" + url;
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is server-side script job. You can look at some MVC framework and the url parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP symfony or codeignitor, if you use .net then create a new MVC project.

But if you only need to change urls like

```
www.mysite.com/mypage.php?something=value
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/value
```

You can do a [mod rewrite](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Apache/Search-Engine-Friendly-URLs-with-mod-rewrite/) in apache or if you're using .net then use [RegisterRoutes](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx) in your global.asax.cs

Comment: So what if we're not using .NET nor PHP?  What's another alternative?

Comment: @CassidyWilliams What are you using?

Comment: @CassidyWilliams I am assuming you know about POST, GET, PUT and DELETE requests and we're talking about how to implement SEO friendly url's like the one used on this site or like `www.myblog.com/camping_in_guilin` instead of `www.myblog.com/article.php?articleid=22`

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET method of form;for example:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
Page: <input type="text" name="page">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

that after submit will go to `index.php?page=yourEnteredPage`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `form` you can submit data to a `location/url` that was given in the `action` attribute of the for, for example

```
<form method="POST" action="http://example.com">
    <input name="first_name" type="text" value="" />
    <!-- Form elements -->
    <input type="submit" name="mySubmitButton" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This form will submit the form data to the given `action` url when submit will be pressed and on the derver data could be retrieve using

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name';];
```

and so on. The method `POST` is used to submit the form in the post array so you can retrieve data using `$_POST['formfieldname']` and if you use `method="GET"` then you can get submitted data from `$_GET` variable, like, `$fname=$_GET['first_name']`. `GET` has limitation of amount when submitting data (safe to use up to 2000 characters `IE's limit`) and is visible to `address bar` of the browser and not being used for login (password) and `POST` can send more data than `GET` and also not visible to address bar.
[You may read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get)

Answer (score 0):

Fairly possible with URL Rewriting
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.