# $_GET not return any value in php

Tags: php, html, get

Hi I am facing a problem with respect to `$_GET` in PHP . I am trying to do payment gateway Integration with EBS. The problem is I am not able to read response I get from URL.

My code to read response is:

```
$RR=$_GET["DR"];
echo $RR;
$DR = preg_replace("/\s/","+",$_GET["DR"]);
```

When I try to check the value using `echo` command it returns `null`. Can some one please help me understand if I need to follow some other process. Also , this works well in WAMP Server I have which uses PHP 5.4.12 however this code is not working when I am hosting it to different server bought from a vendor. PHP version used there is 5.3.

The URL I have is

`http://companyururl.com/response.php?DR=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`

I am trying to read DR value in the form .Looking for a reply.

Comment: Please post either the form code you are using to produce the GET value, or the URL you are using with the manually inserted GET value

Comment: This is the URL I have

Comment: @user3458117 where is the URL?

Comment: Sorry Can you please check URL now , I have updated above in my question description

Comment: Keep in mind PHP is case sensitive. In the title you say `$_get` (incorrect), in your question you say `$_Get` (incorrect) and in your code you say `$_GET` (correct)

Comment: Thanks , in Code it is $_GET and its not working

Comment: try `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: does a shorter GET value yield any results? This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7725515/3330500

Comment: Did you tried to print directly the value of DR?
echo $_GET["DR"];

Comment: May I ask if you have multiple forms in your page? Did you try using $_REQUEST["DR"] instead of $_GET["DR"] to diagnose?

Comment: Yes shorter value works i.e. I am able to print shorter value in using echo command but longer value does not works. I need to have loner value only. I tried var_dumo($_GET) it does not help

Comment: Is there any way I can pass longer value?As this longer value is working in one of my localhost server

Comment: See the examples may be it'll helps you....
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

Check weather request contains data or not by using

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

and then check using

```
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
```

if you are get null in get and data in post it means you have to check form method from get to post as post is default method for sending data. change it to get method. like this one:

```
<form action="" method="get">
....
</form>
```