# Strange php $_GET parameter error

Tags: php, json, urldecode

I am developing a application that sends in jquery a parameter via URL like this:

```
json = JSON.stringify(chk);
base64 = Base64.encode(json);
location = '?route=home/debts/insert&json='+base64;
```

where chk is type array.

Then in the target page I am decoding it in PHP with:

```
$chk = json_decode(base64_decode($_REQUEST['json']));
```

On local server this works miracle, but when into live system, on the server, I can't get the URL parameter, actually the $_GET['json'] or $_REQUEST['json'] are blank, even if I can see them in the URL format

Could someone give me a hint about what am I wrong?

EDIT:

The var_dump($_GET) fired: `array(1) { ["route"]=> string(17) "home/debts/insert" }`

Comment: Perhaps something wrong with the `location` variable?

Comment: Nope, the redirect is ok, the desired page loads fine, only the json parameter isn't

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_GET)` and post the results.  Also, do you use any .htaccess rewrites?

Comment: @Mr.Llama: I have added the result. An yes, the site is using .htaccess but not in this subfolder

Comment: perhaps try to `console.log(base64);` and, as Mr. Llama said, `var_dump($_GET)`. Just want to be sure that everything is getting passed correctly and actually is correctly encoded or whatever.

Comment: Does it reach `$_GET` if you rename the `json` URL parameter to anything else?

Comment: I have found the problem:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the location variable as below (I have inserted a / after insert) and try?

location = '?route=home/debts/insert/&json='+base64;

I have faced a similar issue, where I used Apache in my local machine and IIS on the server. IIS had a config issue and it was not able to handle the URL without the /.

Answer (score 0):

You should URL encode all parameters. You can add URL encoding to the base64 data by adding the following:
`base64 = encodeURIComponent(base64);`

You should also think about URL encoding `route=home/debts/insert` as `route=home%2Fdebts%2Finsert`