# Save data with php-script and hold post-variables on error

Tags: php, mysql, post, return, call

I have already searched an answer here and with google, but I don't found something. Because I'm having trouble ask the right question to find something.

What is the best way for this problem:

**My Page: edit_data.php**
I have a form (`method="post" action="save.php"`). On submit I store the data in a MySQL table.

**In save.php:**
MySQL insert (return the new id of dataset)
if success I call `edit_data.php?id=<new_id>`
if error I call `error.php?msg=<error message>`

The problem is that I lose the data on error.

This is what I want:
- go back to edit_data.php
- show the error directly there
- and I want that all fields contains their original data

I cannot take $_GET, because the data are too big.

Does anyone have an easy solution for me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't use `$_SESSION`? That way, all your data will be saved for the duration of the session, or until you delete it.

Make sure that every PHP document contains `session_start();` before any headers are output, this also goes for any blank space before your `<?php` tag.

To put all your $_POST data in a $_SESSION['POST'] you could do something like,

```
<?php
  session_start();
  foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {
    $_SESSION['POST'][$key] = $val;
 } ?>
```

Then you can access your previous POST variables by accessing `$_SESSION['POST']['KEYNAMEHERE']`

PS: `$_GET` and `$_POST` are interchangeable here

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I use SESSION. I will try it. I post the result here.

Comment: This is very easy. It works. I call `edit_data.php?restore=1` If restore is set, I take the POST-Variables from SESSION Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $_GET is to big, you can edit your php.ini file.

> Please note that PHP setups with the suhosin patch installed will have
>   a default limit of 512 characters for get parameters. Although bad
>   practice, most browsers (including IE) supports URLs up to around 2000
>   characters, while Apache has a default of 8000.
>
> To add support for long parameters with suhosin, add
>   suhosin.get.max_value_length =  in php.ini

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#101469

[Max size of URL parameters in _GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get)