# JsonArrayRequest, url parameter maximum size?

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm new to android,

I'm using a Json webservice in my app to update some database fields, but I have an issue that I can't figure out.

With this one it's working :

```
String url2 = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/ParserUpdateUserAction.do?test=[{\"Mail\":\"xxxxxx@hotmail.fr\",\"Nationality\":\"Spain\",\"City\":\"nimes\",\"Quote\":\"b\"}]";

JsonArrayRequest jor = new JsonArrayRequest(url2, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>().....
```

Not working with this :

```
String url2 = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/ParserUpdateUserAction.do?test=[{\"Mail\":\"xxxxxx@hotmail.fr\",\"Nationality\":\"Spain\",\"City\":\"nimes\",\"Quote\":\"bla bla bla\"}]";

JsonArrayRequest jor = new JsonArrayRequest(url2, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>().....
```

Could the URL parameter size be the problem ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a problem with the spaces - try to use %20 instead of a space

```
String url2 = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/ParserUpdateUserAction.do?test=[{\"Mail\":\"xxxxxx@hotmail.fr\",\"Nationality\":\"Spain\",\"City\":\"nimes\",\"Quote\":\"bla%20bla%20bla\"}]";
```

**Edit:**

There actually is a character limit on GET parameters, but it is about 512, so it shouldn't be a problem here - but you should definitly think of a better solution for longer mails

(Source: [Max size of URL parameters in _GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get))

Comment: yes its working with %20 instead of spaces. I had spaces in one of my fields, the lenght wasn't the problem. Thanks a lot four ur help ThatDude !