# How many parameters get can I use on a link?

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink, get, limit

I'm having some trouble receiving information through `$_GET[' ']`.
I send a request to a PHP document, like this

```
procura_plano.php?plano='+plano+'&operadora='+operadora+'&contrato='+contrato+'&idade='+idade+'&acomo='+acomodacao+'&valor='+valor
```

because I'm using javascript to make the request. But the last value seems not to be set.  Is there a limit of parameters that I can pass through the link?

Sorry for my english :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Comment: unless those variables contain the text of War&Peace, that's not going to be a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please note that PHP setups with the ***suhosin*** patch installed will have
> a default limit of 512 characters for get parameters. Although bad
> practice, most browsers (including IE) supports URLs up to around 2000
> characters, while Apache has a default of 8000.
>
> To add support for long parameters with ***suhosin***, add
> `suhosin.get.max_value_length = <limit>` in php.ini

For More info check this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#101469) or [URL parameters- Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get)

> What w3 Schools say is: Yes, when sending data, the GET method adds
> the data to the URL; and the length of a URL is limited (maximum URL
> length is 2048 characters)

Check this, [GET URL Parameters- w3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)