# encoding base64 image for url

Tags: php, base64, httprequest, urlencode, http-get

I have converted base64 image

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

I understand that I need to replace some characters for url
example

```
$decode = strtr($data, '+/=', '_.,');
echo urlencode($decode);
```

but when I send this printed data
I`m getting 403.shtml
but if I send in same url example abc
it is writing that this is not base64

so as I understand
my host can not get like this big data with GET request.

so I write in .htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 16M
php_value post_max_size 16M
php_value max_input_vars 1000000
```

but I do not know how to change _GET max size

the full link must be lik this

```
example.com/api/booking/a7e59fed68aaf199152c643f9d0ebe77/2016-02-15/morning/2016-03-17/evening/01020201021/ + base64image
```

so it is very long url...

please help me...

P.S.
I`m rewriting url like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

so full url is adding in url variable
please help me

what can I do?
how can I resolve this problem?

thank you for future help.!

Comment: Could you be doing this with POST instead of GET? Also, check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get

Comment: Off the top of my head I think URLs can only contain like 2083 characters to be cross-browser at least, so do POST request as your image base64 looks too long.

Comment: I can not use post. it is nessery to use get. but how can I remove characters limit?

Comment: Browsers have URL bar character limits ([*Source*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/2518525)). So, sending a large base64 string via GET will almost definitely get cut off, ending in invalid base64.

Comment: @maiabardavelidze You can not remove that limit. Get param length should never go over 500 characters for standardized application to work. This is why you use post with file uploads.

Comment: no it is not for browser
I`m sending this request with java application. witch is written by me.
this linki is simple api server and after uploading it is returning little json wwith reqsult: success.