# DocuSign authorization code is empty, the value exceeds 512 characters

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm having a problem reading the authorization code of the DocuSign [oAuth process](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html). 
After sending a request to `/oauth/auth` endpoint to get the code for authentication.

In my PHP installation, the `code` GET paramter from the `redirect_uri` callback is ignoring the `code` value (I'm trying to read the `$_GET` request) because it exceeds 512 in size.

Afaik, `GET` value has only 512 in size in some PHP setups. It looks like this

`eyaB7yDiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQgAAAABAAYABwAANz4cPp_TCAgAAMPEYz6f0wgCALbmrooB_TVEutFTVd_kFA0NACkAAABKT1RGLTZiYTFjZTU5LWI0NWYtNDllNC04MmY4LTg0NGY0N2Y2MzI0OBUAAQAAABIAAAAAABgAAQAAAAUAAAA.DLpJLAe5rlvqp5PKNmxpk12OuY8AB2QRrP_5cONseHOnX8joImefIkt8GEAfiFEu5WPA-aom52ah6puCIzefAgJenXO46W_tevQDgs2OAvl1riJMwMOhnjNxBDtskd5OY2Oe1O6TQ3kn9p7Ln5ZFhsrHQxyjkKnOZzndfI6r5OQTiwB3lakLJnF3XBvt4TN8mFoAxDc-H9znI5w4bgAmi6kxnZ9kM0rYoPLBJG3_uqHJjp8Mra0VGV9BmPjT4BAOAoOGy2y6VP1gxW9X5Fpx-Q6K29BD4ATEqbcctp7wGSLVMyS-o87xSymzovRhdiSMrRdOG2QKY0H-I_d2NUq9jg`

Is there any work around for this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is really a PHP question.

This [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7725515/64904) shows how to extend the max length for PHP installations that limit it.