# PHP GET Error return null

Tags: php, get

Error URL`GET http://xxxx/getSoru.php?notin=66733,17234,65585,16126,1790,45282,2522504,36297,66733,17234,65585,16126,45282,25613,44739,43419,19521,49195,34736,59717,3701,11671,24810,12358,66733,17234,65585,16126,1790,45282,25613,27092,60758,21701,44739,54036,20215,63234,59201,43419,19521,49195,34736,59717,3701,11671,24810,12358,19600,67182,47380,43313,4421,44779,32417,39457,48284,19056,35821,11085,12306,22573,12131,19561,61720,3923,43192,28483,8768,26383,3758,54901,32784,1109,6860,36101,375,1547,16996,15377,37769,5248,8171,25155,49890,8658,22504,36297`

No Error URL`GET http://xxxx/getSoru.php?notin=66733,17234,65585,16126,1790,45282,2522504,36297,66733,17234,65585,16126,45282,25613,44739,43419,19521,49195,34736,59717,3701,11671,24810,12358,66733,17234,65585,16126,1790,45282,25613,27092,60758,21701,44739,54036,20215,63234,59201,43419,19521,49195,34736,59717,3701,11671,24810,12358,19600,67182,47380,43313,4421,44779,32417,39457,48284,19056,35821,11085,12306,22573,12131,19561,61720,3923,43192,28483,8768,26383,3758,54901,32784,1109,6860,36101,375,1547,16996,15377,37769,5248,8171,25155,49890,8658,22504`

Remove 36297 number or any number in url no problem
getSoru.php file

```
<?php
$notin = $_GET['notin'];
echo $notin;
?>
```

I'm not getting `414 Request-URI Too Long` error

Why return empty ?

Comment: That URL is invalid, those comma characters (`,`) need to be URL encoded as `%2C`.

Comment: Apart from that it might be that 1. you have some redirection rules that (accidentally) strip the query arguments and/or 2. you might have the suhosin security extension configured such that it blocks get arguments that exceed a certain length and/or 3. it might be that what you posted is not an actual http get request but something looking similar. Keep in mind that we cannot look over your shoulder. You have to tell us what exactly you do.

Comment: I tried URL encode as %2C, but the result is the same

Comment: OK, so the issue is another one. Still you need to encode, even if things _might_ work under some situations. A URL should be valid according to standards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Max size of URL parameters in \_GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get)

Comment: I'm not getting `414 Request-URI Too Long` error

Comment: Don't use `method="get"` if you need to send very large parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `urlencode()` **No Error URL** string, you get the following:

`66733%2C17234%2C65585%2C16126%2C1790%2C45282%2C2522504%2C36297%2C66733%2C17234%2C65585%2C16126%2C45282%2C25613%2C44739%2C43419%2C19521%2C49195%2C34736%2C59717%2C3701%2C11671%2C24810%2C12358%2C66733%2C17234%2C65585%2C16126%2C1790%2C45282%2C25613%2C27092%2C60758%2C21701%2C44739%2C54036%2C20215%2C63234%2C59201%2C43419%2C19521%2C49195%2C34736%2C59717%2C3701%2C11671%2C24810%2C12358%2C19600%2C67182%2C47380%2C43313%2C4421%2C44779%2C32417%2C39457%2C48284%2C19056%2C35821%2C11085%2C12306%2C22573%2C12131%2C19561%2C61720%2C3923%2C43192%2C28483%2C8768%2C26383%2C3758%2C54901%2C32784%2C1109%2C6860%2C36101%2C375%2C1547%2C16996%2C15377%2C37769%2C5248%2C8171%2C25155%2C49890%2C8658%2C22504`

If you then pass this in a URL by using `echo $_GET['notin']`, it shows the correct value with a string count of 507:

`66733,17234,65585,16126,1790,45282,2522504,36297,66733,17234,65585,16126,45282,25613,44739,43419,19521,49195,34736,59717,3701,11671,24810,12358,66733,17234,65585,16126,1790,45282,25613,27092,60758,21701,44739,54036,20215,63234,59201,43419,19521,49195,34736,59717,3701,11671,24810,12358,19600,67182,47380,43313,4421,44779,32417,39457,48284,19056,35821,11085,12306,22573,12131,19561,61720,3923,43192,28483,8768,26383,3758,54901,32784,1109,6860,36101,375,1547,16996,15377,37769,5248,8171,25155,49890,8658,22504`

if you do the same for **Error URL** using the following below, you get a string count of **513** which means your are over the default character limit if the suhosin patch is installed.

`66733%2C17234%2C65585%2C16126%2C1790%2C45282%2C2522504%2C36297%2C66733%2C17234%2C65585%2C16126%2C45282%2C25613%2C44739%2C43419%2C19521%2C49195%2C34736%2C59717%2C3701%2C11671%2C24810%2C12358%2C66733%2C17234%2C65585%2C16126%2C1790%2C45282%2C25613%2C27092%2C60758%2C21701%2C44739%2C54036%2C20215%2C63234%2C59201%2C43419%2C19521%2C49195%2C34736%2C59717%2C3701%2C11671%2C24810%2C12358%2C19600%2C67182%2C47380%2C43313%2C4421%2C44779%2C32417%2C39457%2C48284%2C19056%2C35821%2C11085%2C12306%2C22573%2C12131%2C19561%2C61720%2C3923%2C43192%2C28483%2C8768%2C26383%2C3758%2C54901%2C32784%2C1109%2C6860%2C36101%2C375%2C1547%2C16996%2C15377%2C37769%2C5248%2C8171%2C25155%2C49890%2C8658%2C22504%2C36297`

I suspect you have the suhosin patch installed so you will need to extend this limit by changing the following in your PHP.ini:

```
suhosin.get.max_value_length = <limit>
```

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php