# No route found in Symfony 4 page

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony4

I have a datatable in my Symfony 4 project.

That datatable calls the following URL to make an Ajax call:

```
/conductor/get_all?draw=4&columns[0][data]=&columns[0][name]=&columns[0][searchable]=true&columns[0][orderable]=false&columns[0][search][value]=&columns[0][search][regex]=false&columns[1][data]=id&columns[1][name]=&columns[1][searchable]=true&columns[1][orderable]=true&columns[1][search][value]=&columns[1][search][regex]=false&columns[2][data]=nombres&columns[2][name]=&columns[2][searchable]=true&columns[2][orderable]=true&columns[2][search][value]=&columns[2][search][regex]=false&columns[3][data]=apellidos&columns[3][name]=&columns[3][searchable]=true&columns[3][orderable]=true&columns[3][search][value]=&columns[3][search][regex]=false&columns[4][data]=runFormateado&columns[4][name]=&columns[4][searchable]=true&columns[4][orderable]=true&columns[4][search][value]=&columns[4][search][regex]=false&columns[5][data]=empresa&columns[5][name]=&columns[5][searchable]=true&columns[5][orderable]=false&columns[5][search][value]=&columns[5][search][regex]=false&columns[6][data]=licencias&columns[6][name]=&columns[6][searchable]=true&columns[6][orderable]=false&columns[6][search][value]=&columns[6][search][regex]=false&columns[7][data]=faenas&columns[7][name]=&columns[7][searchable]=true&columns[7][orderable]=false&columns[7][search][value]=&columns[7][search][regex]=false&columns[8][data]=requisitosWebcontrol&columns[8][name]=&columns[8][searchable]=true&columns[8][orderable]=true&columns[8][search][value]=&columns[8][search][regex]=false&columns[9][data]=infracciones&columns[9][name]=&columns[9][searchable]=true&columns[9][orderable]=false&columns[9][search][value]=&columns[9][search][regex]=false&columns[10][data]=createdAt&columns[10][name]=&columns[10][searchable]=true&columns[10][orderable]=true&columns[10][search][value]=&columns[10][search][regex]=false&columns[11][data]=updatedAt&columns[11][name]=&columns[11][searchable]=true&columns[11][orderable]=true&columns[11][search][value]=&columns[11][search][regex]=false&columns[12][data]=&columns[12][name]=&columns[12][searchable]=true&columns[12][orderable]=false&columns[12][search][value]=&columns[12][search][regex]=false&order[0][column]=2&order[0][dir]=asc&start=0&length=10&search[value]=&search[regex]=false&_=1537540799196
```

Some times, that URL causes a 404 error in Symfony:

`No route found for "GET /%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1537540799196" (from "http://server/conductor"`)

However, sometimes not. This is strange, because when the ajax call throws that 404 error, then I refresh the grid, which call the same URL, it works.

That action is defined this way, in "conductor" controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/conductor/get_all", name="conductor_get_all")
 */
public function getAll(Request $request) {

}
```

Can you give me some lights of what is going on?

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have this issue because of the lenght of the uri. Your example have more than 2000+ characters.

You can try to change the `suhosin.get.max_value_length=<value>` in the php.ini

It also depend of your browser.

To get more info take a look at this issue [Max size of URL parameters in _GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get)

Comment: I also suspected that... but I think if it were the case, request will fail always, won't it? In this case, that error message appears rarely... and when it appears, I do a refresh, calling the same URL with same parameters, and it works.

Comment: Which browser are you using ?

Comment: I am using Firefox