# keywords getting break due to long url in PHP

Tags: php, html, url, get, encode

I am passing all the variables into URL from one file and on the other side in the second page, I am getting all the variables via using     `$_GET` method.

I was done with all things and it was set until this issue came up into my notice.
When I pass keywords which is way long then on then on the other side it gets break.

This is keystring...

```
 “c#” AND “asp.net” AND “sql server” AND (java OR j2ee OR “jsp” OR servlet OR “ejb” OR “jms”) AND html AND xml AND “css” AND Oracle AND (unix OR linux) AND (“app development” OR “arch” OR design OR develop OR hadoop OR python OR rails OR “php” OR websphere OR tomcat OR “big data” OR spring OR hibernate OR eclipse OR log4j OR “ant” OR maven OR “ooad” OR “uml” OR mvc OR “jsf” OR velocity OR struts)
```

so when I send this keyword into url by encoding it, it create a large url and this not the only thing I am passing into URL. So on the other side it gets break like this..

```
 “c#” AND “asp.net” AND “sql server” AND (java OR j2ee OR “jsp” OR servlet OR “ejb” OR “jms”) AND html AND xml AND “css” AND Oracle AND (unix OR linux) AND (“app development” OR “arch” OR design OR develop OR hadoop OR python OR rails OR “php” OR websphere OR tomcat OR “big
```

So any suggestion what should I do on this and I don't want to change my code because I have used   `$_GET` in so many places including pagination.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: GET has a limit on size of data you could pass. I am afraid, you have to use $_POST. If the input gets still cut, then change your post max size settings on your server.

Comment: What would be a better way? $_POST or I would store it into $_session[] variables and use it? I need to use those variables in many places.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get

Comment: If you need to process further between requests, then use $_SESSION. But still, you will have to use $_POST at least once to put them into session.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers