# URL GET variable disappear

Tags: php, uri

I have a simple page to print some data from database.
I use php GET variable, (I know its deprecated, but it's work on local network).

It's working perfectly but if 'valami' length is bigger the 'valami' variable disappearing. When the length is 1061 it does not work

In the php.ini:

```
max_input_vars=3000
```

Also the `aid` variable from the end of the Querystring does get seen by my code? So it does not appear to be a querystring length issue.

What is the problem?

PHP5

```
print_fizet.php?valami=28925|28926|28927|28928|28929|28930|28931|28932|28933|28934|28935|28936|28937|28938|28939|28940|28941|28942|28943|29055|29056|29057|29058|29059|29060|29061|29062|29073|29074|29075|29076|29077|29078|29079|29080|29092|29094|29095|29096|29097|29098|29099|29100|29101|29102|29103|29104|29105|29106|29107|29108|29109|29110|29111|29125|29142|29143|29144|29145|29146|29150|29151|29152|29168|29169|29170|29171|29172|29173|29174|29175|29176|29177|29178|29179|29180|29181|29182|29183|29184|29185|29186|29187|29188|29189|29190|29191|29192|29193|29194|29195|29196|29197|29198|29199|29200|29201|29202|29203|29204|29205|29206|29207|29208|29209|29210|29211|29212|29213|29230|29231|29232|29259|29260|29264|29265|29270|29281|29291|29292|29299|29300|29301|29303|29318|29339|29345|29346|29347|29348|29349|29350|29351|29352|29353|29360|29361|29367|29368|29369|29370|29371|29385|29386|29387|29388|29408|29409|29410|29411|29412|29413|29434|29435|29436|29490|29491|29508|29519|29523|29524|29525|29526|29527|29533|29534|29535|29545|29546|29547|29548|29549|29550|29551|29552|29554|29581&aid=23
```

UPDATE

When I do a

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

The output is

```
array(1) { 
    ["aid"]=> string(2) "23" 
}
```

All I get is the variable from the end of the querystring

When I make a shorter `valami` variable It works:

```
array(2) { 
    ["valami"]=> string(509) "29197|...|29581" 
    ["aid"]=> string(2) "23" 
}
```

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get

Comment: Could you please show us your php code? Otherwise we can only guess and that's not very helpful.

Comment: The code only:
var_dump($_GET);

The output:
array(1) { ["aid"]=> string(2) "23" }

Comment: Can you show us a `var_dump($_GET)` when the query string is a lot shorter and appears to work please

Comment: What happens if you urlencode the pipe character? `|` => `%7C`

Comment: When I make a shorter 'valami' variable Its work:
array(2) { ["valami"]=> string(509) "29197|...|29581" ["aid"]=> string(2) "23" }

Comment: Can you run a `$x = ini_set('max_input_vars', 4000);` and then echo `$x;` This is so you can test if the 'max_input_vars' param in `php.ini` is really set to `3000` as `$x will show you the old value i.e. the value that is really in `php.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're hitting a limit for maximum length of a GET variable - possibly 1024. This is most likely due to the PHP version you use. I've found this note on php.net that may be of use to you:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#101469

Comment: I can't find an answer to that. By default, it's not something that you can change in the ini file. I can't find any clues either about which PHP version supports which length, but I'd imagine if you upgraded your PHP version, you'd get better results. Either way, using GET variables of this length probably counts as a bad practice because of limitations like this (or even browser-limitations in some edge-cases), so I'd rather advise changing to POST.

Comment: OK Guys!
The solution:
suhosin.get.max_value_length change to 3000 (the dafault 512) and work perfectly.
Thanks everybody for help

Answer (score 0):

You can update max_input_vars length from 1000 to 3000 and so on as you want. Try below code to increase input vars length.put this code on starting of the script.

```
ini_set('max_input_vars', 3000);
```

I hope this will helpfull for you.

Comment: Hi Shivam!
The variable now is 3000. The variable in end of url (aid) is work, so I think not the length of url is problem

Comment: This is clearly not the relevant setting here. The default value for this one is 1,000, and since we are dealing with _two_ parameters here only, increasing this to 3,000 will of course achieve nothing at all. This setting is about the _number_ of accepted parameters, not their length.