# Server side J2EE Webservice gets null values on parameters

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I am a newbie at J2ee, What am I doing wrong here ? I am getting null values for my parameters.

HTTP GET URL

> http://:8080/mypath?identity=abcd&identityType=1

Code

```
@GET
@Path("Request")
@Consumes({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
public Response get(@PathParam("identity") String identity,
        @PathParam("identityType") int identityType) {
    System.out.println("Identity "+identity+" IdentityType "+identityType) ;
```

Returns

> Identity null IdentityType 0

Client Side Junit Code

```
    String phoneNumber = new String("abcd");
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);

    String authenticateService = "http://" + SERVER
            + "/mypath?";

    List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identity", phoneNumber));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identityType", String
            .valueOf(1)));
    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
    authenticateService += paramString;
    URI url = UriBuilder.fromUri(authenticateService).build();
    WebResource service = client.resource(url);

    System.out.println(authenticateService);

    ->Exception Here<- String identityHash = service.type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(
            String.class);
    assertNotNull(identityHash);
```

Client println returns

> http://:8080/mypath?identity=abcd&identityType=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, replaced `PathParam` with `QueryParam`

```
@GET
@Path("Request")
@Consumes({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
public Response get(@QueryParam("identity") String identity,
        @QueryParam("identityType") int identityType) {
    System.out.println("Identity "+identity+" IdentityType "+identityType) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `PathParm` you have to adjust the url as well as your method definition

URL

> http://:8080/service/Request/abcd/1

Code

```
@Path("Request/{identity}/{identityType}")
public Response get(@PathParam("identity") String identity, @PathParam("identityType") int identityType)
```

Regards