# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Whenever I am running my web api service I am getting below response

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http:/xxxxxxxxxxx/api/values/Signup_v3?RefferalCode="4566"&Emailid=pavan@fffffmmm&Password=44444444&DeviceID=sdsdsd&PlatformID=3&DeviceToken=dsfnjdsdfkj&Mobilemodel=nojik&Appversion=2.2&MobileOS=hjkdd'.
```

my service is :

```
 [AcceptVerbs("GET","POST")]
 public HttpResponseMessage Signup_v3(string RefferalCode, string EmailID, string Password, string Mobile, string UserName, string DeviceID, int PlatformID, string DeviceToken, string Mobilemodel, string Appversion, string MobileOS)
 {
 }
```

my webapiconfig file is:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769379/why-is-it-that-no-http-resource-was-found-that-matches-the-request-uri-here

Comment: remember `id` is your route parameter. A better approach is to create a POCO class with all those properties and then post as a single object.

Comment: You are not providing username and mobile in your url. Thats causing problem

Comment: @VIVEK Yes I got the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should post/Get with complete paramters:

```
api/Values/Signup_v3?RefferalCode={RefferalCode}&EmailID={EmailID}&Password={Password}&Mobile={Mobile}&UserName={UserName}&DeviceID={DeviceID}&PlatformID={PlatformID}&DeviceToken={DeviceToken}&Mobilemodel={Mobilemodel}&Appversion={Appversion}&MobileOS={MobileOS}
```

For example like this:

```
http://localhost:6642/api/Values/Signup_v3?RefferalCode=12&EmailID=12&Password=12&Mobile=12&UserName=12&DeviceID=1&PlatformID=1&DeviceToken=15&Mobilemodel=345&Appversion=4&MobileOS=4
```

Or Use default value.

Comment: Please past this address and test it:
api/Values/Signup_v3?RefferalCode=12&EmailID=12&Password=12&Mobile=12&UserName=12&DeviceID=1&PlatformID=1&DeviceToken=15&Mobilemodel=345&Appversion=4&MobileOS=4

Comment: In the above service 11 parameters are there.is there any problem

Comment: But in your question you post just 7 parameters

Comment: sorry.   I got the answer

Comment: @AnilKumar.Ok no problem