# REST API Best practices: args in query string vs in request body

Tags: json, http, query-string, rest

A REST API can have arguments in several places:

1. **In the request body** - As part of a json body, or other MIME type
2. **In the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)** - e.g. `/api/resource?p1=v1&p2=v2`
3. **As part of the URL-path** - e.g. `/api/resource/v1/v2`

**What are the best practices and considerations of choosing between 1 and 2 above?**
2 vs 3 is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [REST API Best practices: Where to put parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters)

Comment: In addition to the above, how about using header ?

Comment: Parameters/payloads  that can change session to session but not for each request within a session (like auth tokens)  should be sent in a header. Those  that can change for each request can be sent with a new custom header for each request, but it is verbose, harder to read for end users (for example, a web URL or cURL request) , and just needlessly complicated. They should generally not be sent in the header.

Answer (score 120):

> What are the best practices and considerations of choosing between 1
>   and 2 above?

Usually the content body is used for the data that is to be uploaded/downloaded to/from the server and the query parameters are used to specify the exact data requested. For example when you upload a file you specify the name, mime type, etc. in the body but when you fetch list of files you can use the query parameters to filter the list by some property of the files. In general, the query parameters are property of the query not the data.

Of course this is not a strict rule - you can implement it in whatever way you find more appropriate/working for you.

You might also want to check the [wikipedia article about query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), especially the first two paragraphs.

Comment: A reasonable takeaway to your above analysis is that idempotent operations are best kept in the url query strings and CRUD is best kept to strictly typed response bodies, which essentially takes advantage of SOP and prevents very basic forms of social engineering/phishing attacks

Comment: @Rice R in CRUD is an indempotent operation.

Answer (score 60):

I'll assume you are talking about POST/PUT requests. Semantically the request body should contain the data you are posting or patching.

The query string, as part of the URL (a URI), it's there to identify which resource you are posting or patching.

You asked for a best practices, following semantics are mine. Of course using your rules of thumb should work, specially if the web framework you use abstract this into *parameters*.

You most know:

- Some web servers have limits on the length of the URI.
- You can send parameters inside the request body with CURL.
- Where you send the data shouldn't have effect on debugging.

Comment: is there any source you can cite in terms of the semantic that for post requests the request body should contain the data ?

Answer (score 43):

The following are my rules of thumb...

**When to use the body:**

- When the arguments don't have a flat key:value structure
- If the values are not human readable, such as serialized binary data
- When you have a very large number of arguments

**When to use the query string:**

- When the arguments are such that you want to see them while debugging
- When you want to be able to call them manually while developing the code e.g. with `curl`
- When arguments are common across many web services
- When you're already sending a different content-type such as `application/octet-stream`

Notice you can mix and match - put the the common ones, the ones that should be debugable in the query string, and throw all the rest in the json.

Comment: Selecting how to structure your API based on development convenience is not a good practice.

Comment: Like @EricStein said, you've got it backwards.

Comment: Guys, the reason I asked the question is to get the right answer. Go ahead, write an answer and I'll remove my flawed one. @EricStein

Comment: The second argument for the query can also be used for the body as you can also use `curl` to edit the body.

Comment: @Jonathan apis that are easy to consume via human hands are almost always good apis. Kudos for accurately calling out KISS

Comment: @Jonathan I didn't quite get last point in the query string "When you're already sending a different content-type such as application/octet-stream" what does it mean? could you please give an example. Thanks.

Comment: @AkshayHiremath He's referring to the fact that you might be sending something else in the body, e.g. if you sent a ContentType header like "image/jpeg" you would need to have your message body contain the jpeg data and could not include anything else in it

Answer (score 18):

The reasoning I've always used is that because `POST`, `PUT`, and `PATCH` presumably have payloads containing information that customers might consider proprietary, the best practice is to put all payloads for those methods in the request body, and not in the URL parms, because it's very likely that somewhere, somehow, URL text is being logged by your web server and you don't want customer data getting splattered as plain text into your log filesystem.

That potential exposure via the URL isn't an issue for `GET` or `DELETE` or any of the other REST operations.

Answer (score -1):

According to *Service Design Paterns (2011)* by R. Daigneau, a service can leverage the Tolerant Reader pattern. This ensure that the service function properly when some of the content in the messages or media type they receive is unknown or when data structure vary.

The software is likely to be developed by small incremental pieces over time, and yet the system design evolve naturally. Unfortunately, it introduce the possibility of breaking change as data items are added to, changed, or removed from the message, by any stakeholders.  The service must be forward compatible and under certain condition accept content that it does not fully understand. Exceptions are only throw when the message content clearly violate business rules.

In complement to other answers, we can imagine a service that accept message data from both the request body and the query string for the same requested item representation. This to be compatible with evolving clients.

Comment: While I understand the intent, designing systems to be unnecessarily flexible and forward compatible is not a good practice. The system should be specified to do exactly what it must and meet all requirements, not more not less. Unnecessary to say that added flexibility is also quite often a security nightmare.

Answer (score -1):

Current best practices for Get uses Routes and Query Params, not bodies. According to some posts I've read, there are some systems that will throw failures when trying to read a GET with a body.

However, I believe this system and way of thinking is outdated and it is well proved by simply reading this post and others.  It is my personal opinion that GET requests should read something like the below to allow for HIPPA laws and privacy practices to be best implemented.  Query strings and urls are easily read while sitting between two endpoints, leading to some crazy stupid query strings and other behaviors (like sending Gets in Posts) that simply are a symptom of this outdated practice.  Unfortunately, I am not a major cog in the machine to elicit such change.

We should, very much consider a change to do this as practitioners and pioneers of our art, but we should also maintain the newest and current best practices until that time:

```
get/Humans?page=2&sort=desc
{
Name: "Bob"
Age:"44"
Region:"Greece"
}
```

aka

```
get/route?metasearchinfo
{
   "private":"searchInfo"
}
```

The proposed example has HIPPA type data and private data in the body of a get, while having meta search data in the query string, and the exact URL path where we will query this data before that query.  In this query, we betray no sensitive information, we aren't pretending a Post, and we are keeping things organized.

Again, you can feel free to disagree, but I think this kind of GET makes sense for a future that upholds privacy as an important ideal.  Unfortunately, it isn't best practice at this time and will cause issues with some systems.

For those of you who don't realize it, it is NOW current best practice to put sensitive data in bodies on Gets.  However, the Point I make is that we are still thinking primitively.  What is sensitive, vs. what is not sensitive is defined by law, but law changes and not everyone agrees.  If you went to a restaurant and they announced your name, you might not like that if you were Johnny Depp and trying to be incognito on a date with your brand new girlfriend.

Even better, all you have to do is look at the requests and find the ones with bodies to determine which ones you should decrypt to get the information you want.  If you have a secure system, you can uses paging in the query string, but put all the information in your GET bodies, that way you don't have to worry about what can/can't go into your query strings, and no one just glancing at urls can just determine which bodies to decrypt.

That is why this system of query strings is primitive and needs to be updated; but until that time, as a fellow dev, I will recommend whatever is Best Practice for now.

Comment: The answers above, if followed to an absurdity lead to:
Get/Bob/SSN or Get/Bob?SSN=#####... or Post/Bob { SSN: ##### } (to act like a Get) And we see this answer is wrong because it exposes user data violating laws or doesn't meet the community standard or we encode a query string.  If the answer is wrong or absurd, we should modify the standard to what is right...

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/http-get-with-body#:~:text=In%20most%20situations%2C%20having%20a,highly%20avoided%20for%20many%20reasons is a post about get with bodies at this time, which have been rejected up until 2019 at least.

Comment: HIPPA and similar privacy regulations are important. Compliance with those is an essential part of any specification. If the API requires this level of compliance, transmitting the data securely by using, for example, an encrypted body payload, **is the current best practice**.

Comment: @EricTobias regardless of Hippa/privacy regulations, however, the queryString 
Get/Person?FName=Bob&LName=Hart&MI=L&Age=30&Year=1990

Gets ridiculous, so while HIPPA should definitely be protected and encrypted, if it was encrypted in the QueryString, it would look even worse. 

Which leads to my point, and the fact that I am right, that this is an outdated system.  So I'm confused since this agrees with you, why it might be downvoted.

Comment: Because using a query string for this request isn't the current best practice at all.

Comment: @EricTobias That's the whole point I made.  That we should follow best practices, but that the current best practices are WRONG.  That Gets should utilize Paging information for Query Strings and that all other information should be in a Body, because it is ridiculous to have separate standards based upon HIPPA vs. Not HIPPA.  Just do things correctly, and One Way.  Creating a Secure body, where you don't even know that it might need to be secure is a far better way of thinking.  However, only creating secure bodies for data that needs to be secure invites decryption.

Comment: It's like Where's Waldo, look for the guy in the Striped Shirt.  Look for the guy carrying the money bag or the brief case... If you want truly secure data, you have everyone in a striped shirt carrying a briefcase and a money bag.  That is secure data, otherwise, just find the guy and take the stuff.