# Which Is Better Using POST Arguments Or JSON in REST API?

Tags: php, json, rest, api-design

In previous projects I worked on, our API would take and validate each POST argument individually by value:

```
$username   = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST["username"] : null;
$password   = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST["password"] : null;
```

[Multidimensional arrays can be a bit tricky this way, though.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772096/posting-multidimensional-array-with-php-and-curl/)

For a new project, I am consider a more object-oriented approach, and taking the JSON needed to construct objects instead of each individual field:

```
$user       = isset($_POST['user'])     ? new User($_POST['user']) : null;
```

Which practice is more common, and why? Are there extra security risks using one or the other?

Comment: As long as you are consistent it doesn't really matter. If one method expects number and another JSON it will cause confusion. IMHO, JSON is more future proof. If tomorrow you decide that one number is not enough you can just add another parameter to the JSON instead of rewriting the whole method.

Comment: See more general question about POST query vs JSON body: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385559/rest-api-best-practices-args-in-query-string-vs-in-request-body

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any security advantages over either. If someone intercepts the request then they will be able to see the POST data whether it is in different arguments or just the body.

Make sure that you are using SSL to prevent prying eyes.

As far as JSON body vs POST arguments, it really depends on how you will be using the API. Are you going to use a front-end JS framework or jQuery? Then JSON will probably be easier for you. Does your API return JSON? Then it should probably accept JSON too.

Remember that you could always handle different content types based on the `Content-Type` header!

Answer (score 2):

For developing REST API, I prefer to use `JSON` as **Request** (than POST arguments) and **Response**.

For Client side, making json request is not difficult. All language has support `JSON` now.

And for Server side (**PHP**), retrieving `JSON` in body request is not difficult too.

```
// $data will be array of data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

And using `JSON` for both **Request** and **Response**, will make API Documentation easy to read.

And for security section, AFAIK there is no problem using `JSON` in body request,