# Node rest API: put request is not updating the request data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Trying to update data using PUT request. But, the data is not updating and returning the previous data in postman.

Postman put request:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/actors/5daa8f1c5845ad0b5826b8d9?name=Tom
```

Postman response:

```
{
    "createdAt": "2019-10-19T04:16:13.317Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-10-19T04:16:13.317Z",
    "_id": "5daa8f1c5845ad0b5826b8d9",
    "name": "scarlett johansson",
    "birthday": "1980-10-14T00:00:00.000Z",
    "country": "usa",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I have also tried to use findByIdAndUpdate. Didn't get the result. Any help would be appreciated.

Controller:

```
exports.updateActor = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const actorId = req.params.actorId;
        const data    = req.body;

        const updateActor = await Actor.findById(actorId);

        updateActor.set(data);

        const actor = await updateActor.save();

        // res.status(200).json({ message: "Data has Updated Successfully!" });
        res.send(actor);

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
};
```

Router:

```
router.put('/actors/:actorId', Actor.updateActor);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your postman request is `http://localhost:3000/api/actors/5daa8f1c5845ad0b5826b8d9?name=Tom` so look like the data to update will be in `req.query` instead of `req.body`.

**Note**: You should put the data to update in the body instead of query like you're doing.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385559/rest-api-best-practices-args-in-query-string-vs-in-request-body).

Comment: Solved. I have a question. The question is: if i want to send data using req.body, then what will be the procedure?

Comment: For postman you can put the data in body section like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc3PD.png

Comment: Got it. I have tried x-url-encoded. As, updating data via query is not a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve the ObjectId error use the below code.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const updateActor = await Actor.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":mongoose.Types.ObjectId(actorId)},data, { new: true });
res.send(updateActor);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Please use following code for getting update data 

 Actor.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":ObjectId(actorId)},data, 
 { new: true}).then((updatedData) => {
 res.send(updatedData);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. Response code is 200. but, data is not updating in database.

Comment: Please now check

Comment: const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');  add that line

Comment: I have tried the following: Actor.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":mongoose.Types.ObjectId(actorId)}, data, { new: true}).then((updatedData) => {
            res.send(updatedData);
        });

and, that works. 

We need to add mongoose.Types before ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.updateActor = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const actorId = req.params.actorId;
        const data    = req.body;

        const updateActor = await Actor.update({"_id":actorId},data);


        // res.status(200).json({ message: "Data has Updated Successfully!" });
        res.send(updateActor);

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
};


try thiss...
```

Comment: response code is 200. but, data is not updating in database. Database connection is also fine. because, i can get, delete data.