# fastapi connection using Python requests

Tags: python, rest, scikit-learn, fastapi

I have a fast api for a simple ML model. THE post request for API is

```py
@app.post('/predict')   
def predict_species(data: str):
    data_new = np.array([data])

    prob = lr_tfidf.predict_proba(data_new).max()
    pred = lr_tfidf.predict(data_new)
    return {'Movie Review': data,
             'Predictions':f'{pred[0]}',
            'Surity for Review': f'{prob}'}
```

Now, when I try to connect it using python `requests` module, it is giving me error.

```py
import requests

review = {'data': 'THIS IS A POSITIVE MOVIE'}
resp = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/predict", json=review)   

print(resp.content)
```

The content is

```py
b'{"detail":[{"loc":["query","data"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}'
```

The Terminal Error Message is

```py
INFO:     127.0.0.1:45730 - "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

FastAPI expects a query parameter like this, but you are sending a json in the request's body.

This expects a query parameter

```py
@app.post('/predict')   
def predict_species(data: str):
```

You need to use `Body()` function or a Pydantic model.

```py
from fastapi import Body

@app.post('/predict')   
def predict_species(data: str = Body(...)):
    ...
```

Comment: It's also well explained in the docs. I guess OP didn't go through the docs first...  https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#singular-values-in-body

Comment: How should I send a query parameter?

Comment: Check my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64936353/13161155) to see the difference between them.