# Is it safe to make a POST request with JSON data using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working on web application where I need to send some data using ajax with post method. So I have two choices to send data whether in JSON format or query prams. I'm confused which should I use? and is it safe to send data in JSON format?

Comment: sending data in the body is a bit safer than sending it in the query params... if you use HTTPS and send data in the body of a POST request it's pretty safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lucasreta mentioned, if you use HTTPS, it doesn't *really* matter either way.

Both methods are widely used. I know that Google accepts a Post request with query params and responds with a JSON object for [ReCaptcha Server side validation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify).

Sometimes, the decision to use one or the other (or both) is dependent on how easy your chosen back-end technology makes it for you to either parse out query params or serialize JSON.

I will say that there *is* a general trend in using JSON in the request body as opposed to query params.

I found a couple of SO questions that are more down the lines of what you are asking...

[REST API Best practices: args in query string vs in request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385559/rest-api-best-practices-args-in-query-string-vs-in-request-body)

[REST API Best practices: Where to put parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters)