# Best Practice for designing a REST API for subsets of a resource

Tags: rest

Given a URL structure like this:

```
 GET           /user/giftcards/:id
```

When returning list with all my giftcard:

```
 GET           /user/giftcards
```

And here comes my questions, what is best practice for URL structure if I also want to return subsections of the giftcards, like received or sent?

Today I do this (but I know its wrong since the URL should represents the noun / resource (here: giftcard)

```
 GET           /user/giftcardsreceived
 GET           /user/giftcardssent
```

The way I see it there are two "better" solutions:

```
 GET           /user/giftcards/received
 GET           /user/giftcards/sent
```

or

```
 GET           /user/giftcards?filter=received
 GET           /user/giftcards?filter=sent
```

Im leaning towards the request param solution with filtering since the other solution could potentially conflict with the GET based on id.

Any pointing in right direction appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [REST API Best practices: Where to put parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters)

Comment: Thanks, didnt fint it when I searched, good one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer the query param style as the status is usually a property of the resource rather than a brand new resource itself.

Check out Brian Mulloy's presentation on [api design](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design). It's as good a place to start as any

Answer (score 2):

Since this corresponds to a sub list of elements, this should be served by the same resource that addresses such list of elements. So using query parameters would be better in my point of view.

The following link could give you additional hints:

- Designing a Web API - https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/. See section "Filtering data

Hope it helps you,
Thierry