# Backbone Model and Collection url design with a NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, rest, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone, NodeJS and web development and am struggling with the proper design of my Backbone Collection and Model `GET` requests and routes on my NodeJS server.

At first I only used Models and specified the `urlRoot` which worked perfectly. Once I added my Models to a Collection it used the Collections' `url` parameter which was fine once I realized what was happening.

Say I have model "Book" and a collection "Library" defined as below:

Book

```
app.Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {
       title: 'No title',
       author: 'Unknown'
   }
});
```

Library

```
app.Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Book,
    url: '/books'
});
```

Now if I do a `GET` request on the model the url will be `'/books/:id` which has a route specified on my node js server and I would return the book with the specified id.

**My Question**

I don't know what is good practice and design regarding the `GET` request on the Collection. Say if I want to fetch a Collection of books by a certain author my url will look something like `/books/:author_id`, but this would go to the same route as my Model `GET` request on my node js server.

How do I distinguish between the Model `GET` request and Collection `GET` request on my node server? I don't want to use a quick hack, but would like design it properly.

What is considered best practice to pass 'filter' parameters with a Collection `GET` request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [REST API Best practices: Where to put parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we need to have multiple filters like that we do something like this.

`/books/:id`

`/books/byAuthor/:authorId`

`/books/bySearchTerm/:searchTerm`

Although in our case we're using Angular and Repos to get our data, but the url pattern works regardless of what you're client side is structured like.

Comment: So the Model will use the default `url` on the Collection, but you would then change the `url` before you do a `fetch` on the Collection?

Comment: That's what we did when we used Backbone. Although to be honest we found backbone difficult to use as complexity grew, and we went with a Angular system, and used normal javascript objects in a standard DDD style.