# How can I use the dojox Rotator with gestures?

Tags: javascript, mobile, dojo, slideshow, gestures

As you may know, with the [(Auto)Rotator](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/widget/AutoRotator.html) you can create slideshows. Unfortunately, the UX when using touch events or [gestures](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/gesture.html) isn't what you'd expect. For example, if you wanted to use a swipe gesture to skip to the next slide, the slide wouldn't actually stick to your finger/pointer because the Rotator only provides simple transitions, which are invoked by itself through basic commands like "next".

Is it possible to adapt the (Auto)Rotator to work like a typical gesture-based slideshow, and - if so - how? Or would it be less of a hassle to just program it myself?

Comment: This comment regards your comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4026505/1525840). You were clear that there are specific rules and the ambiguity is negligible when designing REST. Would you care to share a link pointing to a resource (pun intended) that discuss it? I'm asking, because in my experience, there's often need to be creative and flexible and it would be good to know if the flexibility is perhaps voiding the convention.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Not off the top of my head, no. Sorry.