# Modeling API Restful Resources to find patient by appointment number

Tags: php, api, rest

i have follow tables:

**appointment**
 id
 value
 patient_id

**patient** 
 id 
 name 
 birthdate 
 race_id

How the best way to create API resource if I search patient by appointment value?
Option 1: `GET /patient?appointment=111111`
Option 2: `GET /appointment/{value} and return JSON Patient`
 
Option 3: `using nested resources like GET /patient/{n}/appointment`
Option 4: have any ideas?

tks

Comment: What's your definition of best way? Performance? Elegance? Clarity?

Comment: clarity / performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 2** sounds better:

Only one change - use appointments instead of appointment.

GET /appointment**s**/{value}

(Here I am assuming that you are having patient and patient's appointment summary data with you).

Your other options were -

**Option 1**: GET /patient?appointment=111111 - I would prefer query parameter instead of search parameter. See this - [REST API Best practices: Where to put parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters)

**Option 2**: GET /appointment/{value} and return JSON Patient - This was close according to me.

**Option 3**: using nested resources like GET /patient/{n}/appointment - You need appointment data. Hene, use it after /appointment. i.e. /patients/appointments/{n}. (If you are going with this.)

Comment: Yeah, I prefer Option 2 too. I will change the resource to appointments as you said