# Designing REST API Endpoints: path params vs query params?

Tags: php, rest, slim, restful-architecture, restful-url

Take these two tables in a database:

- `topics` that contains a list of topics
- `terms` that contains a list of uni, bi and trigrams
- `baggings` with columns `topic_id`, `term_id` and `weight`

A term can be used in several topics so how would you build the API endpoints? It's a query params vs path params...

**Path Params**

> GET https://localhost/topics/:topic-id/terms/

**Query Params**

> GET https://localhost/terms/?filter_by=topic&filter_value=:topic-id

The last solution can also be useful to perform various `terms` operations and searches. The first (Path Params) can only be used in relation to the given `topic`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REST API Best practices: Where to put parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

You can support both if you want to.
I usually use query parameters when I need to search for something with dynamic parameters.

In order to fetch all terms associated with a topic id, I would go with

```
GET https://localhost/topics/:topic-id/terms/
```

This should list all terms for the `topic_id`

But in case your search had more filters you wanted to use, I would go ahead and support query parameters.  Say you want only terms which match a certain type for a particular topic, then I would use the query parameters.

I personally don't prefer to lookup a specif topic-id like this.

```
GET https://localhost/terms/?filter_by=topic&filter_value=:topic-id
```