# Post parameter in path or in body

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am creating Rest API but I am confused in URL structure. I have to send just one parameter to server in my Post request. should I send it through path variable or in request body? what are the best practices?

Example Current URL:

```
api/v1/users/{id}/name/{name}
```

`name` is the variable I want to send to server for to change state

Thanks

Comment: A POST implies the existence of a body. If you only want to update the name then send a PATCH to `api/v1/users/{id}`.

Comment: @zeroflagL I am sorry, what is PATCH?

Comment: Just another method. Like POST, but used to update only parts of a resource. Like in your case.

Comment: ok got it, so in other words if I want to use POST then i should send state changing parameters through body. right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: really appreciate that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [REST API Best practices: Where to put parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

URL usually identifies resource you want to update.

So the data should go inside in request body

To update user name you may send this to server:

```
POST api/v1/users/{id} HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

name=string
```

Comment: Is there any supporting reference for do and don't for state changing variable?

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question in correct way. You may read about how REST approach  could be implemented for example here 
http://jsonapi.org/format/ or here http://www.odata.org/getting-started/understand-odata-in-6-steps/

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that