# REST API filtering with related resources best practices

Tags: java, rest, search

What is the best practice to include related resources in the search query?

my resources are:

```
/projects
/participants
/questions
/questionAnswers
```

the query would be something like: get all participants who are:

```
- between the age of 20 and 40 and,
- male and,
- selected answer X of question y
```

would it be something like

/participants?search=gender:male,age>=20,age<=40,question:x,answer:y

Is there a better or a standard way for this type of queries?

Comment: Personally, I'd rather use application/x-www-form-urlencoded and send it as POST. That's a personal opinion and I could be wrong. Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters

Comment: Maybe [GraphQL](https://github.com/facebook/graphql) would be more feasible for your case?

Answer (score 0):

you can use object serialization & filters.
like:

*/participants?filter={gender={male}, age={between={20, 40}}, question={x}, answer={y}}*

for given example with:

- gender     = male, female
- age        = (1...99) OR between={start, end} OR till={end} OR from={start}
  etc..

**in this case**, you have the possibility to filter more specific and/or combined.
A combination for example:

*/participants?filter={gender={male, female}, age={21,22, 23, from={40}}, question={x}, answer={y}}*

**result:** gender male and female with age 21, 22, 23 and from 40 till 99 (or what you want)