# Formatting an API request to the REST API

Tags: rest, api

I am trying to get historical USD prices for BTC from the Coinbase API. The relevant section of the documentation is [here](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-sell-price). I've never interacted directly with an API before, so at the moment I'm just trying to figure out how to format the request.

To get the current price, this works:

https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot

However, if I want to get historical prices I need to specify a date as indicated in the docs, but I can't seem to get the format right. I'm sure this is a standard format of which I am just unaware, so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I've tried:

https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/2018-01-01

https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/date/2018-01-01

https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/resource?date=2018-01-01

https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/resource/date=2018-01-01

(something along the lines suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters))

What is the correct formatting for the API request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should format the request as

```
https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot?date=2018-05-21
```

And you should include a CB-VERSION

```
CB-VERSION: 2017-08-07
```

if you want to avoid an API warning

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.