# Endpoint with two path parameters

Tags: rest

I'm learning [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and I have a question.

Is there a scenario where the endpoint `person/pathParm1/PathParam2` is legitimate?

For example:

```
person/ben/stiller
people /2/4
```

As far as I understand REST, query parameters should be used for searches:

```
person?firstName=ben&secondName=stiller
```

or

```
person/2/order4
```

Comment: more info on this can be found here: [REST API Best practices: Where to put parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters). If something is valid syntax, or legitimate, is determined by the application which receives the request (because that should throw an error, when the question is incorrect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

So if you want to have a [URI template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) with multiple variables to expand, and more than one of those variables are expanded as path segments, that's *fine*.

For example, you'll notice that your browser has no trouble with this resource identifier:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74969638/endpoint-with-two-path-parameters
```

which might reasonably be produced by expanding variables into a template like

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/{id}/{hint}
```

---

> As far as I understand REST, query parameters should be used for searches:

That's not a [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) constraint, although for the special case of the web it turned out that way.  This is primarily a historical accident: we didn't have standards for URI templates when the web was young, which meant that searches came about from the standardized implementation of HTML form submissions (application/x-www-form-urlencoded key value parameters replacing the query part of the form action)

REST does say that we use [resource identifiers](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) to... identify resources; and that we all use the same general purpose resources (ie: conforming to the production rules defined in [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-A)), but without constraints on the spelling or semantics of those identifiers.

Example: URL shorteners *work*.

(Note: your misunderstanding is a common one, and not at all your fault; the literature sucks.  FWIW, I was once where you are; [Stefan Tilkov's 2014 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM) was the one that really got my own thinking straightened out.)

That said, you might find a "query parameters should be used for searches" constraint *coming from somewhere else*; a local style guide, for example.

---

> this means I could also make a restful endpoint like this: `api/person/{firstName}/{lastName}` instead `api/person?firstName=ben&lastName=stiller` ?

Yes; you can use either of those spellings for your resource identifiers, and all of the general purpose components out there will still "just work" -- because they are treating the resource identifier as semantically opaque.

Comment: ok, so this means I could also make a restful endpoint like this:

api/person/{firstName}/{lastName}
instead
api/person?firstName=ben&lastName=stiller
?

Comment: What's the purpose of the second path parameter in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74969638/endpoint-with-two-path-parameters? The following endpoint also works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74969638 so the second parameter is not really necessary

Comment: I suspect that the second path parameter is used for no other reason than to help human beings who are, for example, looking at a the URI in a browser history, to recall which identifier goes with which web page.

Comment: ok I see. Thank you. And regarding the api design: I could also make a restful endpoint like this: api/person/{firstName}/{lastName} instead api/person?firstName=ben&lastName=stiller ?

Comment: Yes - you might prefer the latter if you are expecting to use HTML forms as your "URI template"; you might prefer the former if you are going to be using relative references to link to other resources in the same hierarchy.  Notice that these are purely mechanical concerns; they have nothing to do with the meaning of the sub parts of your identifiers.