# What are most used URL parameters?

Tags: url, search, parameters

from my experience I know that most used parameters in urls are like
'id=';'cid=';'user_id='; 'pid=' and other.

Do you have any other similar most used parameters?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I understood it right, but the URL parameter name -almost- don't have limited options. You could also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568929/what-are-the-url-parameters-naming-convention-or-standards-to-follow

Comment: yes I know, but for example when I use advanced search like inurl:".php?id=" I got more results than inurl:".php?cat_id=" so I just looking for parameters which give me more results on google. Thank you anyway for your reply.